# How to mine information from a game with no API

Tags: web, web-scraping

I want to gather information from a game called Tera. It's an MMO and I'd like to gather prices on specific items in the broker on a daily basis. I'm wondering how people build programs that mine data from games that don't have an API.

There are many websites that mine data from a game called League of Legends. These sites include:

http://www.lolking.net
http://www.lolnexus.com
http://www.elophant.com

And league of legends does not have an api in place. How do these websites accomplish this? Can someone link a tutorial or a guide or sample code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can get the prices on in the game store (https://store.enmasse.com/tera)? You can download the the HTML source and parse it. You could also reverse engineer game cache, but it would be harder and probably against its terms of service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time, there was no public API for League of Legends and these sites were getting information by scraping the RTMP API used by the client. However, there is now a public API for League of Legends: https://developer.riotgames.com